# ASP.Net MVC ajax controller call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call the controller by clicking a button. My goal is getting date values from view and calling other data from controller, but ajax thing is so bugging me out. So I made a testing one, but it still does not work.

I followed several tutorials and SO questions, and this is how I figured out to call the controller method ("testtest") through javascript ajax functions. Here is [the tutorial](http://www.makeitspendit.com/calling-asp-mvc-controllers-from-jquery-ajax/) that I followed for the last time.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSelectDate').click(function () {
        alert("working");
        var text= $('#txtStartDateI').val();
        var button= $('#btnSelectDate').val();
        alert(text + " " + button);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/testtest",
            type: "post",
            datatype: "text",
            data: { btnSelectDate: button, txtStartDate: text},
            success: function (data) {
                ('#testarea').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#testarea').html("ERROR");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the method "testtest":

```
[HttpPost]
public string testtest( string btnSelectDate,string txtStartDate ) {
    return ("btnValue : " + btnSelectDate + "\ntxtStartDate: " + txtStartDate);
}
```

When I click the button, the alerts are working, but it does not call the method "testtest" in Homecontroller. I set the breakpoints in controller, but it does not go through. After it shows the alert dialog, the whole page blinks and nothing has been changed. I tried to make the `<div id="testarea"></div>` get the text value.

I tried different URL forms like:

```
url: '@Url.Action("testtest","Home")'
url: 'localhost/Home/testtest'
```

But it still does not hit the controller.

Does ajax require any special scripts to add? (I guess I added ajax scripts since there are some links containing 'ajax'.)
Or do I need to do something special to call the method using ajax?

The bellow is my whole code. This is my controller "Home":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace haha.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult View() {
            return View("View");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string testtest( string btnSelectDate,string txtStartDate ) {
            return ("btnValue : " + btnSelectDate + "\ntxtStartDate: " + txtStartDate);
        }
    }
}
```

View:
(and for the scripts, I think there are several scripts which are duplicated, but I can't figure those out. What can I remove?)

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Web;
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>View</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

        <script src="~/scripts/jquery-*.*.*.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".Datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    nextText: 'next Month',
                    prevText: 'previous Month',
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    currentText: 'Today'
                })
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnSelectDate').click(function (event) {
                    alert("working");
                    var text= $('#txtStartDateI').val();
                    var button= $('#btnSelectDate').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/testtest",
                        type: "post",
                        datatype: "text",
                        data: { btnSelectDate: button, txtStartDate: text},
                        success: function (data) {
                            ('#testarea').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $('#testarea').html("ERROR");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is test area
        <div id="testarea"></div>
        <hr />
        <p></p>
        <div>
        <form id="formDTInsurer">
            StartDate:
            <input type="text" class="Datepicker" id="txtStartDateI" name="txtStartDate">
            <button type="submit" id="btnSelectDate" name="btnSelectDate" value="InsurerDate">Select</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Following [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)'s comment, I inspected the console using chrome tool. The following is the error.

```
                                                                      jquery-1.5.1.js:869 
Uncaught TypeError: b.parents(...).addBack is not a function
    at Object.parse (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:19)
    at Object.resolveWith (jquery-1.5.1.js:862)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.5.1.js:420)
    at HTMLDocument.DOMContentLoaded (jquery-1.5.1.js:1055)
parse            @ jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:19
(anonymous)      @ jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:19
resolveWith      @ jquery-1.5.1.js:862
ready            @ jquery-1.5.1.js:420
DOMContentLoaded @ jquery-1.5.1.js:1055
```

Since there were more errors with these scripts, I commented out some of those, and it actually reduced the number of errors. The only left is the one above.The following is what I now have in current html file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

    <!--<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="~/scripts/jquery-*.*.*.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: There is no errors, but it does not work as what I meant..

Comment: And include only one copy of the scripts and in the correct order - `jquery-{version}.js` then `jquery-validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and `jquery-ui.js` (but that is not related to your error)

Comment: Of course there are error(s) (otherwise it would hit the method)

Comment: Oh :'D yeah then there are errors.. but how could i find those? in the web browser, nothing changes. I will fix the scripts one thanks!

Comment: Use your browser tools and inspect the console.

Comment: I'm now home but I will do so tmr, thanks :)

Comment: @pebble please try this one `url: '../Home/testtest',
data: '&btnSelectDate=' + button + '&txtStartDate=' + text,`

Comment: Try removing `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: It's awkward, the command url: '@Url.Action("testtest","Home")' should do the trick, how did you configure routes ?

Comment: @KiRa Thanks for the comment, but that still has the same error.

Comment: @Berkay Thanks for the comment, but that also couldn't fix..

Comment: @MichelAmorosa I remember I read some of mapping routes during researching, but I did not make something like that. I thought that is not a mendatory one..

Comment: @pebble can you post this line of code `b.parents(...).addBack` from your codes?.

Comment: @pebble routing seems not to be a part of your problem here.
FYI, some routes are defined by default, see Startup.cs, Configure method.

Comment: @Kira I had no addBack function in my codes. However that error is now fixed after I changed jQuery 1.5 to jQuery 1.11! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @MichelAmorosa Oh I see, I'll look for it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @pebble great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is awkward to include two versions of jquery (1.5 and then 1.7), you have to find the right order and have only one jquery include. Maybe replacing the 1.5 by another one ?

Answer (score 1):

send your parameters by `json` type :

```
  type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ btnSelectDate: button, txtStartDate: text})
```

and use   `alert(text);` and `alert(button);`and make sure their values are correct(not null)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The alerts are getting the values what they are supposed to get. However, the error which I added in the post happens again..

Comment: You're welcome,
It is awkward to include two versions of jquery (1.5 and then 1.7), you have to find the right order and have only one jquery include.
Maybe replacing the 1.5 by the 1.7 ?

Comment: Yesss you are right!! I had no idea so copied all the scripts, but after I read your comment, I deleted 1.5 and change to the 1.11 (I think this is the newest when I searched).. and not there is no error! Thank you so much :D

Comment: I copied the comment as an answer so you can validate it as an answer.

Have a nice day